# Download all rows in the datatable in the single click

Tags: r, shiny

In the below application, If I need to download all 32 rows, I will have to go to all pages and then download that is very time consuming. Is there a way to download all rows in the first page it self (Keeping only 10 rows in first sheet)

```
library(shiny)
library( DT )

# Define UI for application that creates a datatables
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Download Datatable")

  # Show a plot of the generated distribution
  , mainPanel(
    DT::dataTableOutput("fancyTable")
  ) # end of main panel

) # end of fluid page

# Define server logic required to create datatable
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$fancyTable <- DT::renderDataTable(
    datatable( data = mtcars
               , extensions = 'Buttons'
               , options = list( 
                 dom = "Blfrtip"
                 , buttons = 
                   list("copy", list(
                     extend = "collection"
                     , buttons = c("csv", "excel", "pdf")
                     , text = "Download"
                   ) ) # end of buttons customization

                 # customize the length menu
                 , lengthMenu = list( c("All") # declare values
                                       # declare titles
                 ) # end of lengthMenu customization
                 , pageLength = 10


               ) # end of options

    ) # end of datatables
  )
} # end of server

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to set the parameter `server = FALSE` in `renderDataTable`. The reason for this is, when `server = TRUE` which is the default setting only the rows visible are delivered to the widget.

```
library(shiny)
library( DT )

# Define UI for application that creates a datatables
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Download Datatable")

  # Show a plot of the generated distribution
  , mainPanel(
    DT::dataTableOutput("fancyTable")
  ) # end of main panel

) # end of fluid page

# Define server logic required to create datatable
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$fancyTable <- DT::renderDataTable(
    datatable( data = mtcars
               , extensions = 'Buttons'
               , options = list( 
                 dom = "Blfrtip"
                 , buttons = 
                   list("copy", list(
                     extend = "collection"
                     , buttons = c("csv", "excel", "pdf")
                     , text = "Download"
                   ) ) # end of buttons customization

                 # customize the length menu
                 , lengthMenu = list( c("All") # declare values
                                      # declare titles
                 ) # end of lengthMenu customization
                 , pageLength = 10


               ) # end of options

    ) # end of datatables
  , server = FALSE
  )
} # end of server

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Hope this Helps!!

Comment: Thanks . U mentioned True and in the code it’s is false. I think it should be false. Also when I deploy this RStudio connect server, keeping server = False will not effect anything right?

Comment: I don't belive it will affect anything but the data deliverd to the datatable widget